# Javascript map method doesn't work in reactjs project

Tags: reactjs

I am completely new at react and I am following a tutorial. For this tutorial I have the following component called user-list.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class UserList extends Component {

  createListItems() {
   return this.props.users.map((user) => {
     return (
       <li>{user.first}</li>
     );
   });
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <ul>
       {this.createListItems()}
     </ul>
   );
 }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

  return {
    users: state.users  
  };

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserList);
```

And here is my reducer-users.js

```
export default function() {
  return [ 
    {
      id: 1,
      first: 'Bucky',
      last: 'Roberts',
      age: 71,
      description: 'Bucky is a React developer anbd Youtuber',
      thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/7yUvePI.jpg'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      first: 'Joby',
      last: 'Wasilenko',
      age: 27,
      description: 'Joby loves the Packers, cheese and turtles',
      thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/52xRlm8.jpg'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      first: 'Madison',
      last: 'Williams',
      age: 24,
      description: 'Madi likes her dog but it is really annoying.',
      thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/4EMtxHB.jpg'
    }
  ]
}
```

And now I am getting an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, I removed the map function and returned any other data and it works fine, except when it tries to map the data.

Comment: looks like `this.props.users` is not an array. show your root reducer. by the way, reducer should have signature `(state, action)`, so rewrite your user reducer.

Answer (score 0):

When using the ES6 syntax for React Components, in your constructor function you need to bind any custom bethods you define on your class.

add the following to your UserList definition

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.createListItems = this.createListItems.bind(this);
}
```

and you should be good to go. If you don't like doing this, you can also revert to the React.createClass({}) method for creating your component class.

Comment: It didn't work, behavior is the same and I keep getting the same error with the map function

Answer (score 0):

you should have something like this for your code to work correctly.

```
// user reducer file

const initialState = [ 
  {
    id: 1,
    first: 'Bucky',
    last: 'Roberts',
    age: 71,
    description: 'Bucky is a React developer anbd Youtuber',
    thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/7yUvePI.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first: 'Joby',
    last: 'Wasilenko',
    age: 27,
    description: 'Joby loves the Packers, cheese and turtles',
    thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/52xRlm8.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    first: 'Madison',
    last: 'Williams',
    age: 24,
    description: 'Madi likes her dog but it is really annoying.',
    thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/4EMtxHB.jpg'
  }
];

export default function usersReducer(state, action) {
  return state;
}

// root reducer file

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import usersReducer from 'your path to users reducer file'

export default function rootReducer() {
  return combineReducers({
    users: usersReducer,
  });
}

// store file

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from 'path to root reducer file';

const store = createStore(rootReducer());

export default store;
```